# Using iptables to bypass VPN based on user

Tags: iptables, openvpn

Running the latest LTS Xubuntu and am trying to route traffic from processes initiated by one user (let's say 'jsmith') around a VPN. I think iptables is my only hope here?

The relevant adaptors are eth0 and tun0, and here's my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.189.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192-168-1-1.tpg 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.189.1.1      10.189.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.189.1.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.189.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
f.06.01a8.ip4.s 192-168-1-1.tpg 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192-168-1-1.tpg *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree? Crucially, the IPs I want to send naked traffic to are changing daily - but they will always be initiated by the same user. I think routing from that user to the outside world is possible, but I'm very concerned about going the other way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make user specific changes to `iptables` when that user connects to the OpenVPN server, the most obvious solution is to use OpenVPN's `--client-connect` script .. any `bash` compaible script should be able to maipulate `iptables` so long as your server is running with the approriate `--user/--group` rights .. IE: root.